# How to create a drop down or multiple select filter in dashboard that will filter all worksheets?

Tags: tableau-api

I have null and non-null values in my dataset. I would like to create a drop down which will consist of -Display All, Null or Non-Null values. This should filter the dataset so that all worksheets in the dashboard are filtered out based on it. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **parameter** will help you accomplish this.

```
Create... > Parameter > String > List > ["All", "Non-Null", "Null"]
```

From there, create a **calculated field** which references the parameter.

```
If [Parameter] = "Non-Null" Then 
    (If IsNull([Nullable Field]) = False Then 'Show' Else 'Hide' End)
ElseIf [Parameter] = "Null" Then 
    (If IsNull([Nullable Field]) = True Then 'Show' Else 'Hide' End)
Else 'Show'
End
```

Finally, place the newly created calculated field on **filter** and select only 'Show.' To filter all worksheets, right click on the filter and select `Apply to worksheets > All using related datasource` or specific sheets of your choosing.

Comment: Or, you could just apply the filter to all the relevant sheets by right-clicking the filter pill and selecting the `Apply to Worksheets` option.